# maven-javadoc-plugin and inheritDoc for Java API core classes

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am writing my own Java 8 Stream implementation and want to inherit the Javadocs from the original `java.util.stream.Stream` interface. However I cannot get it working. The generated Javadoc does only show my documentation but not the documentation from the extended Stream interface.

So for example, the javadoc of this method does only contain the text "Some additional information" but not the documentation from the `Stream` interface.

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 * Some additional information.
 */
@Override
public Stream<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> predicate) {
  // ... my stream implementation...
}
```

This is my configuration of the maven-javadoc-plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <links>
      <link>http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/</link>
    </links>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Do I miss something in this configuration? I set `source` and `target` to 1.8 in the maven-compiler-plugin. So according to the documentation of the [maven-javadoc-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#detectJavaApiLink), the java API should be detected automatically.

There was also a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401642/how-do-i-make-javadoc-inheritance-work-for-external-apis-with-maven2/3402644) on Stack Overflow but the answers there do not seem helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is expected, `javadoc` only copies comments from classes that are inside the source path. From [Method Comment Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDFAGJH):

> **Note:** The source file for an inherited method must be on the path specified by the `-sourcepath` option for the documentation comment to be available to copy. Neither the class nor its package needs to be passed in on the command line. This contrasts with Release 1.3.n and earlier releases, where the class had to be a documented class.

However, the sources of your JDK aren't in the source path, so [`{@inheritDoc}`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDGJCHC) won't copy it. They need to be added explicitely; the [Javadoc FAQ has this entry](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#incrementalbuild):

> **Inheriting Comments from J2SE** - Your code can also automatically inherit comments from interfaces and classes in the J2SE. You can do this by unzipping the `src.zip` file that ships with the SDK (it does not contain all source files, however), and add its path to `-sourcepath`. When `javadoc` runs on your code, it will load the doc comments from those source files as needed. For example, if a class in your code implements `java.lang.Comparable`, the `compareTo(Object)` method you implement will inherit the doc comment from `java.lang.Comparable`.

So, to make it work:

1. Locate the sources of your JDK and unzip them somewhere.
2. Configure the `maven-javadoc-plugin` to add those sources with the [`sourcepath`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#sourcepath) parameter.
3. With the above, we would also generate the Javadoc of the JDK itself, which is unnecessary (we only want to inherit), so we can use [`subpackages`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#subpackages) to specify only our packages. Alternatively, we can use [`excludePackageNames`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#excludePackageNames) to exclude the JDK packages.
4. The JDK (at least Oracle JDK) also uses new Javadoc entries, namely `@apiNote`, `@implSpec` and `@implNote`. Those are custom tags that need to be added with the [`tags`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#tags) parameter.

Here's a sample configuration, where the path to the JDK sources is `/path/to/jdk/sources` (you could also use an environment variable, a property set by profile, etc.) and your own source files are all in the package `my.package`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourcepath>/path/to/jdk/sources:${basedir}/src/main/java</sourcepath>
        <subpackages>my.package</subpackages>
        <tags>
            <tag>
                <name>apiNote</name>
                <placement>a</placement>
                <head>API Note:</head>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>implSpec</name>
                <placement>a</placement>
                <head>Implementation Requirements:</head>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <name>implNote</name>
                <placement>a</placement>
                <head>Implementation Note:</head>
            </tag>
        </tags>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Generating the Javadoc, for example with `mvn javadoc:javadoc`, will correctly resolve the `{@inheritDoc}`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I also managed to extract the `src.zip` directly during the maven build by declaring a `system` scope dependency to `${java.home}/../src.zip`. Having this dependency I can use the maven-dependency-plugin's unpack-dependencies goal with includes to the packages that I need. For the `java.util` package (I don't need more), this will take only a few extra seconds.

Answer (score 1):

[Tunaki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38708383/14731) is great but as of Java 10 you have an even better option. If you pass `--override-methods=summary` to the Javadoc tool it'll push all inherited methods down to a "Methods declared in class X" section down below. This will list the inherited methods. Clicking on method names will take the user to the Javadoc definition in the base class.

See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8187386 for background information.